# npm install fails due to private git repository both ssh and https connections

Tags: git, npm, ssh, package.json

I have the following package.json file and I am trying to run npm install, but it fails.

```
    "test": "git+https://<TOKEN>@github.build.test.com/test.git",
```

I have ssh key matched to github. However even I write the following, it always run with https.

```
    "test": "git+ssh://git@github.build.test.com/test.git",
```

In both case, I encounter following error message

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.build.test.com/test.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
npm ERR! remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.
npm ERR! remote: See https://github.build.test.com/settings/tokens or https://github.build.test.com/settings/ssh
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://github.build.test.com/test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

If I run above command separately, it works.

```
git ls-remote -h -t https://<TOKEN>@github.build.test.com/test.git
git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.build.test.com/test.git
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: @Vix What is missing from my answer? Can you edit the question and share more details about your specific case?

Answer (score 2):

First if you have any [`url.<base>.insteadOf` directive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) in your git configuration:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config -l|grep -i insteadOf
```

And if not, set one of your own:

```
git config url."ssh://git@github.build.test.com".insteadOf  https://github.build.test.com
```

See then if it is still using https.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use "git+ssh://git@github.build.test.com/test.git" you should be able to clone this repository without passing credentials. 
Simple `git clone git+ssh://git@github.build.test.com/test.git` shouldn't ask for pass or username.

You probably need to configure your git public/private keys. Your locally used key for cloning must be added to repository config. For example for github is possible to configure it on https://github.com/settings/keys